# Google sign button dissapears when i refresh - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

Sign in button only works when the server starts, but as soon as i refresh on the browser the sign in button is gone and this error message shows:

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8V4Q.png)

And when I use firefox in the console it says window.gapi is undefined

I am not sure why this error happens, I would appreciate it if you can help :) thank you.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signin2' of undefined
    at App.renderGoogleSignInButton (index_bundle.js:32253)
    at App.componentDidMount (index_bundle.js:32216)
```

this is my react code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
 this.signOut = this.signOut.bind(this)
}
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('google-auth-loaded',
    this.renderGoogleSignInButton());


}

signOut() {
var auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
auth2.signOut().then(function () {
  console.log('User signed out.');
});


}

onSignIn(googleUser) {

   var auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

    console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token)
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  }

renderGoogleSignInButton() {
    window.gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
      'scope': 'email',
        'theme': 'light',
        'longtitle': true,
        'onsuccess': this.onSignIn,
        'onfailure': this.onSignInFailure
    });
}


onSignInFailure(error) {
    console.error(error);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.signOut}>logout</button>            
        <div id='my-signin2'></div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

My html :)

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div class="" id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=triggerGoogleAuthLoaded" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function triggerGoogleAuthLoaded() {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('google-auth-loaded'));
    }
  </script>
```

2 ways of solving this: 
1 remove async defer from the html script
2 remove the () so it looks like this
window.addEventListener('google-auth-loaded',this.renderGoogleSignInButton);
so it doesnt trigger instantly

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Removing async defer fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

After page reload it will happen due to library not loaded fully.

Just debug with setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {this.renderGoogleSignInButton()}, 1000);
```

Increase the time limit value. Like 5000 . And check may be it's a library load issue.

Comment: Not a solution at all